# TSQL parameter with NULL value does not enter IF condition

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, if-statement, null

I have a query that looks like this:

```
use [dbName]

DECLARE @profile_id int
SET @profile_id = 18
DECLARE @test int

SET @test = (SELECT user_profile_id FROM tbl_profiles WHERE id = @profile_id)

SELECT @test as test

if @test = NULL
    SELECT 1

else 
    SELECT 2
```

I know that the value in the table is null, and I can see that @test is correctly being set to that value because the first SELECT shows:

```
 |test
1|NULL
```

However, in the IF condition the variable is not being treated as NULL because only the third SELECT is returned, showing:

```
 |(no column name)
1| 2
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `IS NULL` (**not** `= NULL`)

```
if @test IS NULL
    SELECT 1

else 
    SELECT 2
```

You can **never** compare `NULL` with the "regular" comparison operators - you **always** have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` only.

And `NULL` really isn't a *value* per se - it's the **absence** of a value...

Comment: Just to confirm, If I change the connection settins i.e. `SET ANSI_NULL OFF` even then can't I compare iT?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta: maybe - but that's definitely **not recommended** and violates the SQL-92 language standard. Don't rely on a non-standard compliant behavior... also, the [SQL Server 2012 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) mentions that in the not too distant future, the ability to set this to `OFF` will be removed...

Comment: Thanks for information. I was just adding it to my knowledge. Not intended to do that although :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `IS NULL`. Instead of:

```
if @test = NULL
    SELECT 1

else 
    SELECT 2
```

Try this:

```
if @test IS NULL
    SELECT 1

else 
    SELECT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use condition (id = @profile_id **AND** @profile_id **IS NOT NULL**)

`SELECT user_profile_id FROM tbl_profiles WHERE (id = @profile_id AND @profile_id IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: well, this was just a query for me to test how the IF ELSE conditions would work with a NULL value, but in the actual query I will have to to different actions depending on whether or not that entry is NULL.